# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP With SSL Certificate Already Removed from CPanel

Tags: redirect, ssl, http-status-code-301

I want to ask something. I have an online store. My online store uses SSL for the entire website. I also get backlinks with https:// link. Now I do not use SSL again and wish every time people click on the link https will go to http. I've removed the SSL certificate from my CPanel. I've tried several .htaccess and php code, but none of which succeeded. Please help me, thank you. Here's some code I tried:

.htaccess HTTPS to HTTP code: http://pastebin.com/uDuB1S5K
PHP HTTPS to HTTP code: http://pastebin.com/UsDQnB8v

That became my problem is .htaccess and PHP code above always detect website's SSL, I want the code to detect whether the page is opened using the url http or https, not using SSL/not.
Note: The redirect is 301.

Thank you very much for your help.

Regards, Darnin.

Comment: Why are you putting ON for HTTPS option in your .htaccess file?
Make it OFF and as far as I know there is no option to redirect from HTTPS to HTTP. While we can do it HTTP to HTTPS.

Comment: Oh, I see. I tried to make off but still nothing changed. So there is no way to redirect traffic from https to http without using an SSL certificate?

Comment: Unfortunately no. In order to do a redirect, you need to "pick up the phone" when people call on the HTTPS line.

Removing SSL service means there's nothing listening on port 443, which means users will get a browser "can't connect" error.